# If we change default database name in asp.net mvc 4 default example , what are the places we should change?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I just changed my Database in MVC 4 Default sample in Visual Studio 2012.but new database contains all the tables that included Default DB,

I understood few places that should change when we change DB.

These are the changes I did

1.Under "Filter" Folder "InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs" File

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("HECConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

2.Under Models Folder "AccountModels.cs"

```
    public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("HECConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserProfile")]
```

3.In the Web.config File Connection  string

```
      <connectionStrings>
  <add name="HECConnection"         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=HEC;                              Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\HEC.mdf"                               providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
```

I like to know rest of the places I should change ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that's all you need, did you try to rebuild your application?

Comment: yeah , its working properly , just want to know if there any other changes addition to mine